# URL reading: works in main, but not in constructor

Tags: java

I am developing a software based on the API of Alphavantage. I designed an object for each stock, which will have an ArrayList storing historical prices for the stock. To do that, I read a url that leads me to a cvs file, from which I can extract the data I need. This works in the main function, however, in the constructor it does not. With `public Stock(String ticker) throws Exception` I get an error saying

```
 error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to
 be thrown
         Stock msft = new Stock("MSFT");
```

Without `throws Exception` I get

```
 error: unreported exception MalformedURLException; must be caught or
 declared to be thrown
         URL url = new URL(link);
```

I don't really understand what is wrong with my code. Could someone help me? Here is the full source code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.Math.*;

public class SmartBeta {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Stock msft = new Stock("MSFT");
    }
}

class Stock{
    //ArrayList to store prices
    private ArrayList<Double> prices = new ArrayList<Double>();

    //stock constructor
    //the argument takes the ticker symbol, in order to find the 
    //corresponding data
    public Stock(String ticker){
        String link = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_WEEKLY_ADJUSTED&symbol="+ticker+"&apikey=PRIVATE_KEY&datatype=csv";
        URL url = new URL(link);
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";
        URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        int i = 0;
        //we read the csv file returned, seperate it by commas, convert the 
        //numbers into doubles and store them in the ArrayList
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (i == 0) {
                ++i;
                continue;
            }
            String[] data = inputLine.split(cvsSplitBy);
            prices.add(Double.parseDouble(data[5]));
            ++i;
        }
        in.close(); 
        System.out.println(prices);   
    }

}
```

Comment: You just need to put a *try/catch* around your *new URL(link)*. Just declare the *url* variable outside, and assign to null, than assign to the URL object in the try/catch. You also need to check if it is null before use it.

Comment: If one method throws an exception, then that means the calling code must catch that exception

Comment: You must handle the exception. You should study the [Exceptions lesson in the Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare your Stock constructor, could throw an IOException, so in signature add Exception declaration:

```
public Stock(String ticker) throws IOException {...}
```

and then, in your main method handle this exception:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Stock msft = new Stock("MSFT");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //exception - do something
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Or maybe just a `MalformedURLException`.

Comment: MalformedURLException extends IOException. It is thrown when you create new URL object. But in this case you need also to handle exceptions from connection and stream which both throws IOException.

Comment: Then you are right; IOException is the correct thing then.